# Webview load all HTML files from assets directory

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-assets

In my app,i want to display the HTML files in my assets folder in WebView.I tried this

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");
```

This is working.But what i want is a method which can be called anywhere and pass the html file in assets as parameter and display it in the WebView.Somebody please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create A public method which uses webview and pass String of ur String

```
public void setUrl(String urlString){
{
wv.loadUrl(urlString);
}
```

For this your WebView must have Global scope. Then only u can access it.
 call anywhere like `setUrl(path);`

Comment: Can u show LogCat.? U have to initialize webview before calling this method.

Answer (score 1):

Create this in your activity containing webview

```
public void load(String fileAddress){

    wv.loadUrl(fileAddress);

}
```

And to call it just type

```
load();
```

If you want to call it from any other class then first create a instance like this -

```
className class = new className();
//Change className to name of the activity containing webview

class.load();
```